# How to select single checkbox in default Listview Builder with index in flutter

Tags: database, firebase, listview, flutter, checkbox

```dart
Checkbox(
  checkColor: Colors.red,
  activeColor: Colors.white,
  onChanged: (bool value) {
    dataOfArray.add(arrayOfId);
    var n = dataOfArray.indexOf(arrayOfId);
    print("data$n ---OfArray${dataOfArray}---${[arrayOfId]}");
    setState(() {
      //                        if (_checkboxval) {
      //   setState(() {
      //     _checkboxval = false;
      //   });
      // }else {
      //   setState(() {
      //     _checkboxval = true;
      //   });
      // }
      if (
          //dataOfArray[n]== arrayOfId
          dataOfArray.indexOf(arrayOfId) != -1) {
        this._checkboxval = value;
        print("dataOf///////////Array$dataOfArray");
      }
      // else this._checkboxval=value;
    });
  },
  //value: arrayOfId[''],
  value: this._checkboxval,
);
```

Here I am trying to select a single check bocx into the default listview builder.

But it is selecting all the checkbox into the created listview builder.
please help if you have faced this type of error.

In that i take an dynamic listview of data using firebase in that particular list i give the data with checkbox and on particular checkbox all checkbox are selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a list of an object first, then you need to update the checked box status into the list and update status.

> For example:

**PODO class:**

```
class ObjectClass {
  int id;
  bool checkBoxStatus;

  Users({this.id, this.checkBoxStatus});

  Users.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    checkBoxStatus = json['check_box_status'];
  }
}
```

**Class file:**

> List dataOfArray; // initialize your data from api or
>   whatever

```
Checkbox(
    checkColor: Colors.red,
    activeColor: Colors.white,
    onChanged: (bool value) {

    setState(() {
    dataOfArray[arrayOfId].checkBoxStatus = value;
    });
    },

    value: dataOfArray[arrayOfId].checkBoxStatus,
    )
```

> Complete example available:
>   http://codesfor.in/flutter-listview-with-checkbox/

If you have any doubt, you can ask.